# If $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert \le \lvert x-y \rvert ^2$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ then $f$ is a constant function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

> > Assume that $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert \le \lvert x-y \rvert ^2$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $f$ is the constant function.

My first thought was to use continuity of $f$, so that we get that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}, \lvert x-y \rvert<\delta \implies \lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert < \epsilon$.

So choosing $y$ so that the above property holds, we get that $\lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert \le \lvert x-y \rvert ^2 <\delta^2$

Using the inequality I found (supposing it is correct), how would I continue to prove that $f(x)=f(y)$, and so their difference must be zero.

Comment: What can you say about the derivative of $f$?

Comment: Asked many times on the site. Consider the points $x_k=x+\frac{k}n(y-x)$, the hypothesis applied to each $(x_{k-1},x_k)$ yields $|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|\leqslant\frac1{n^2}|x-y|^2$. Summing these from $k=1$ to $k=n$ and applying the triangular inequality yields $|f(x)-f(y)|\leqslant n\cdot\frac1{n^2}|x-y|^2$ and you are done.

Comment: @fourierwho That one does not know a priori that it exists and that one does not need it to solve the exercise, perhaps?

Comment: The inequality explicitly shows that the derivative exists and is 0.

Comment: The proof using the derivative is fine, however it does require invoking the mean value theorem or similar to prove $f'(x) = 0 \implies f(x) = C$ to finish the proof. Thus it's a bit more of a complex proof than the primitive proof suggested above which just requires the triangle inequality. What is best is a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: Related: [How to show that every $\alpha$-Hölder function, with $\alpha>1$, is constant?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603291/how-to-show-that-every-alpha-h%c3%b6lder-function-with-alpha1-is-constant) ; [Proving that a function satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y|^3$ is constant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900703/proving-that-a-function-satisfying-fx-fy-leq-x-y3-is-constant) ; [If $f$ satisfies $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leqslant(x_1-x_2)^2$ on an interval](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885871/if-f-satisfies-fx-1-fx-2-leqslantx-1-x-22-on-an-interval-then-it-i)

Comment: @achillehui [Try this one](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clvert%20f(x)-f(y)%20%5Crvert%20%5Cle%20%5Clvert%20x-y%20%5Crvert%20%5E2%24&p=1)

Comment: @Winther thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the definition of the derivative.

> $$0\le\lim_{x\to y} \left|{f(x) - f(y)\over x-y}\right|\le \lim_{x\to y}|x-y|=0$$

So the function is differentiable with derivative $0$ at all points.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x+h$ with $h\ne 0$. Then $$0 \le \left| \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|<|h|$$ and so $$-|h| \le\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \le |h|.$$Take limit for $h$ to zero then $$f^\prime(x)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to understand this is, when $x\neq y$, we can divide by $|x-y|$ to get that:
$$\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq |x-y|$$
Now, one characterization of the derivative of $f$ is:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{y\to x}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$$
As out inequality is valid for all $x,y$, we can pick a sequence $y_k$ with $y_k\to x$, $y_k\neq x$ and look at:
$$\lim_{k\to\infty} \left|\frac{f(x)-f(y_k)}{x-y_k}\right|\leq \lim_{k\to\infty} |x-y_k|$$
The left-hand side of this is just the derivative at $x$, so we have that:
$$|f'(x)|\leq 0$$
From this, it's clear that $f'(x) = 0$, and so $f(x)$ is constant.

Comment: take a function takes the values $\pm3$ (rational/irrational) and then absolute value will have limit but not the function. Saying left hand side is $|f^\prime(x)|$ is assuming that $f^\prime(x)$ exists.

Comment: I don't believe that function satisfies the initial constraint, as if you have $i, r$ (irrational and rational) within epsilon of eachother, then the difference of your function would be $3-(-3)=6$, which for suitably small epsilon would contradict our assumptions on $f$.

Comment: I am saying it for general. Here it is true, since it exists. But you used it without knowing/showing it exists.

Comment: Indeed this is no proof that $f'(x)$ exists, only that if it exists then it is $0$.